# How to write dead simple native SERVER program (not app) for Android devices?

Tags: android, linux, pthreads, native

First of all, I *believe*, it's not a duplicate question. I don't want to write a native app with NDK, I just want to use Android device as a cheap Linux *server*. Server, in this context, means a program, which has *no UI*. Also, the server is written in bare C++, but uses no libraries at all, so that's why should that question differ from others.

**The story**

We've written a small server for Linux, it has a webserver interface, so you connect to it with a vanilla browser, and you can play with it. We've compiled it to Linux/x86, Linux/ARM (GuruPlug), Linux/PPC (some kind of NAS), and Mac OS X Darwin platforms.

The Linux/ARM version also runs well on my Palm Pré smartphone. I've just copied the executable onto my phone (in webOS scene, there's no such thing like jailbreak, there's an official "developer mode", which if you activate by typing a secret key combination, you can log in to your phone with ssh or use local ssh app). So, our small server program (daemon, may say) is running on even the smallest Linux devices. (It's funny, when connect with your giga-powered desktop machine's browser to a smartphone server.)

The server program is designed to run on even the smallest Linux (as I said, it runs on NAS, router, smartphone), **it requires only STDLIB and PTHREADS**.

**The question**

What't the straight way to get that simple server program run on an Android device?

- We have no Android device yet. But I assume, any ARM-based one will do. The server's memory footprint is so small, that it will be no problem.
- I assume, the device must be rooted to copy executable to it and run.
- I don't want to install a whole new Linux on the device. It should keep running Android, while our server works in the background. The Linux distribution which enough for Dalvik, is enough for our server, I'm pretty sure.
- The server should use no external things (USB, touchscreen, audio, camera, mic - thanks, not) only a port for webserver (e.g. 8080), which is not allocated by Android.
- I have ARM GCC toolchain, the installation of it is not the part of the question (except if there're tricks).
- The installation of the program should be manual (scp, whatever). Also, I don't want to make a package or any automated deployment.
- The problem of the launching of the server program is another question, we'd ignore now.

So, I want just do the same thing with an Android device (phone, tablet), just as I did on my webOS device: copy the server program and run on it. Computers are for that, running programs, aren't they? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need a rooted android device. 
I recommend that you install `busybox` to get a bunch of nice command line tools such as `wget, tar, gzip` and many more.
You can get shell access to your device by using `adb shell` and then `su` to get root access. You can either use `adb push` or `wget` to put your server on the device.
The /system partition is mounted as read only and depending on the manufacturer there are a lot of protections that restrict you from writing there so you should copy your server somewhere on the /data partition (e.g. `mkdir /data/myserver`). After this, everything should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I'll try it. Is there a way to start my server automatically on system boot? I think /etc is also write-protected (even if Android starts the usual Unix way). Maybe, it depends on the machine / Android version. Thx for the answer.

Comment: Done. I just copied the ELF to a rooted device, it runs without a word. It has a webserver interface on the port 8080, it works too.

Answer (score 5):

I have not really tried it, but it should be possible to use the ARM GCC compiler you have, or the one provided by the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/) to compile native application, the same as you would use it on your desktop.

If your application is small (not too many files), you can manage the compilation by hand (or in a simple Makefile). The following commands are from the [LuaJIT compilation guide for Android](http://luajit.org/install.html#android):

```
/tmp$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        printf("Hello world!\n");
        return 0;
}
/tmp$ NDK=/opt/ndk
/tmp$ NDKABI=8
/tmp$ NDKVER=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3
/tmp$ NDKP=$NDKVER/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
/tmp$ NDKF="--sysroot $NDK/platforms/android-$NDKABI/arch-arm"
/tmp$ ${NDKP}gcc $NDKF -o test test.c 
/tmp$ file test
test: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

Obviously, use `linux-x86` instead of `darwin-x86` if you are on Linux (not Mac OS X, also not sure about Windows), and change the path to `NDK` to where you installed it.

Now you have to move the compiled binary somewhere to your Android device, and run `adb shell` to see if it works:

```
/tmp$ ADB=/opt/sdk/platform-tools/adb
/tmp$ $ADB push test /data/
332 KB/s (3343 bytes in 0.009s)
/tmp$ $ADB shell
# /data/test
Hello world!
```

Comment: I have no problem with compiling (finally! it was a nightmare, see related question), the question is that can I use Android as a kind of ARM Linux-distro.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the question is more a sysadmin issue (how to install your executable on your Android device) than a developer issue (how to cross compile a C program for Android)?

Comment: Yep, I have no problem (have to add: finally!) with compiling to ARM, but I don't know anything about "Android distro".

Answer (score 1):

I have a chroot partition with my android galaxy phone. It is arm with floating point processor, so all kinds of compilers work. Warning to you: the busybox/android distro utils don't run as GNU software. Their tar have problem unpacking the first thing I tried. POSIX tar not supported. Their zip have problem with some field 1 or 8. Their mount works like somthing from space. Their partition itself that you will want to have software put on does not support sym link. After a few weeks working on the chroot partition, I start to feel that the whole android is just a new underlying BIOS, with lots of firmware.